# How can I remove background noise in this kind of image using OpenCV, Python, CPP, Matlab or any possible way?

Tags: python, c, matlab, opencv, image-processing

Original Image

[image: Noisy Image]

Now, I want to remove all the dots in background without affecting inner side of object so I can make this image as below:

---

Expected Image Output

[image: Expected Image Output]